# Assigning Defined elements to a 2D Array C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, assign

I have a 3 large groups of integers that I would like to add to different rows of an array. These integers are defined as follows:

```
#define APARTMENT1_USAGES {0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.189, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.074, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.065, 0.167, 0, 0, 0, 0.048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0}
    #define APARTMENT2_USAGES {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.130, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.176, 0, 0.125, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.161, 0.000, 0.039, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0.000, 0.109, 0, 0.032, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.100, 0, 0, 0.063, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0.025, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.378, 0, 0.147, 0.229}
    #define APARTMENT3_USAGES {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.088, 0, 0}
```

I have shortened these just to show the idea, they are usually 30x24 elements. 
What I am trying to do is load each of these into a row of a 2D array, but am getting a syntax error without an explanation. I have tried it as follows:

```
double apartmentUsage[3][30*24];
apartmentUsage[1][30*24] = APARTMENT1_USAGES;
apartmentUsage[2][30*24] = APARTMENT2_USAGES;
apartmentUsage[3][30*24] = APARTMENT3_USAGES;
```

Comment: `double apartmentUsage[3][30*24] = {APARTMENT1_USAGES, APARTMENT2_USAGES, APARTMENT3_USAGES};`. You have to do it in the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

One of the errors you are facing is as follows:
If you define `array[3]`, you can have three values stored in `array[0]` , `array[1]` and `array[2]`.
In your code. its defined as `apartmentUsage[3][..]` but starts with `1`.
Should be like this-

```
int multiply=30*24;
apartmentUsage[0][multiply] = APARTMENT1_USAGES;
apartmentUsage[1][multiply] = APARTMENT2_USAGES;
apartmentUsage[2][multiply] = APARTMENT3_USAGES;
```

`**BUT**` this too won't completely solve your problem. Try doing it in the initialization itself as pointed in the comments - 
`double apartmentUsage[3][multiply] = {APARTMENT1_USAGES, APARTMENT2_USAGES, APARTMENT3_USAGES};`

Comment: Using `30*24` is probably preferable to using `multiply` because the latter makes the array into a VLA (variable-length array), whereas the former makes it a regular, fixed size array.